# C# Finding DataTable rows with duplicate values ignoring differences due to case, spaces or punctuation characters

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a simple DataTable of 2 columns: ProductCode and ProductName.

I want to find all rows which have identical Product Names, ignoring any differences due to spaces, case or punctuation characters.

Example: if there are 3 rows with ProductName as `"Item 1", "Item - 1" and " ITEM'1"`, all should be identified when I search for rows using any of the 3 names.

Suppose my list of punctuation or noise characters is "`-_. '`" etc.

How can I achieve this in the most performance efficient way, if my table has around 10000 rows, and I want to find possible duplicates of each row?

Using SortedList, I can write a custom class implementing the Comparer / Comparable interface.

What are my options in DataTable?

Thanks.

Comment: Question: why are you even using `DataTable` here? it doesn't sound necessary, and it sounds like you have options for doing it other ways...

Comment: The code is already written, and I am writing an enhancement to existing code, so not using the DataTable will involve a whole lot of rewrite. Yes, I can populate 1 more SortedList using the DataTable, but just want to know whether it is possible to do this using DataTable

Comment: so, normalizing the data is out of the question? I am with the other Marc in that it doesn't sound necessary. Why would you load a datatable with 10k rows and search that. More efficient to use SQL for what its good at and do a parameterized query with Regex's to handle your variations.

Comment: The DataTable is getting populated from several Excel sheets. There is no SQL database involved.